# ragged right justification in cls template

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, templates

I'm using a latex template to format my dissertation. The template has been provided as a .cls file and accompanying tex file. One of the requirements is that the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables not be full-left justified, but rather just left justified (ragged right). I'm still relatively new to latex, but I can usually figure out how to troubleshoot issues. But I really don't know how to work with a .cls file. I would really appreciate it if someone could take a look at the .cls file, and give me advice on how to modify it to remove the full-left justification found in the table of contents, list of tables and list of figures.

[You can download here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34644229/latex_diss.zip) a simplified version of my dissertation that shows the issue. You have to execute the "PTitle_thesis.tex" file more than once to get the content to fully appear.

Thanks! I really appreciate any help anyone can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change `\@tocrmarg`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@tocrmarg{1in plus 1fil}%adapt the 1in to you liking
\makeatother
```

But imho it sounds rather odd that a class given to you doesn't fulfil the requirements.

Comment: thanks! I agree with you, it is odd, seems like an oversight or something.